# Refactoring slow functions in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe

I am refactoring an old application to make it a bit more responsive and I have a form that is using devExpress components and it creates a custom grid using the CallbackCustomDrawPreviewCell, the problem is that this function is very slow it takes about 0.09s per call but it is call about 30 to 60 times each time the form is open so the form can take 2.8s to 5.6s to open.
I normally program with C# and Object-C/Swift where we can dispatch a block to be process in the background, but as far as my research go we don't have nothing similar in Delphi, it seems that normally in Delphi a new thread has to be a whole new and independent piece of code. Is my assumptions correct?

If so what is the best type of solution to improve speed in this kind of situation? (I am using Delphi XE)

(in case it helps: I also just bought AQTime to try help me figure out how to improve this but I had no luck so far with it, still need to dig into the manuals a little more. But it did help me find the problem in the speed in this particular callback)

Thanks in advance.

**The function is:**

```
procedure TtvdAvaOutageManagementForm.CallbackCustomDrawPreviewCell(Sender: TcxCustomTreeList; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxTreeListEditCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
const
  AlignFlag = DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_END_ELLIPSIS;
  cnFontColor = clBlue;
var
  AFaultId: variant;
  aFault: TtvdFault;
  aLocalities, aFaultLocalities: TStringList;
  i: integer;
  aLocality: string;
  Rect: TRect;
  size: TSize;
  AText: string;
begin
  { colour the preview text blue }
  ACanvas.Font.Color := cnFontColor;
  AText := AViewInfo.DisplayValue;
  aLocalities := TStringList.Create;
  aFaultLocalities := TStringList.Create;
  try
    AFaultId := AViewInfo.Node.Values[FtvdTree.GetColumnByFieldName('FaultId').ItemIndex];
    if (not VarIsNull(AFaultId)) then
    begin
      ACanvas.Brush.Color := COLOR_FAULT;

      aFault := FtvdFaults.tvdGetFault(AFaultId);
      if Assigned(aFault) then
      begin
        ACanvas.Brush.Color := aFault.tvdFaultColor;

        ACanvas.Brush.Color := aFault.tvdFaultColor;
        ACanvas.FillRect(AViewInfo.BoundsRect);
        CopyRect(Rect, AViewInfo.BoundsRect);
        InflateRect(Rect, -1, -1);
        Inc(Rect.Left, FtvdTree.OptionsView.IndicatorWidth);
        ACanvas.Font.Color := cnFontColor;

        { if all the localities are in the fault then bold the preview text,
          else need to do it manually (i.e. only bold the localities that are
          in the fault }
        if aFault.tvdAllLocalities then
        begin
          ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
          ACanvas.DrawTexT(AText, AViewInfo.BoundsRect, AlignFlag);
        end
        else
        begin
          CopyRect(Rect, AViewInfo.BoundsRect);

          aLocalities.Text := StringReplace(AText, ', ', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
          aFaultLocalities.Text := StringReplace(aFault.tvdLocalities, ', ', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
          for i := 0 to aLocalities.Count - 1 do
          begin
            ACanvas.Font.Style := [];
            { draw a comma if this is not the first locality }
            if i > 0 then
            begin
              size := ACanvas.TextExtent(',');
              DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, ',', 1, Rect, DT_LEFT or DT_NOPREFIX);
              Inc(Rect.Left, size.cx);
            end;

            aLocality := aLocalities[i];
            if aFaultLocalities.IndexOf(aLocality) >= 0 then
            begin
              ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
            end;

            size := ACanvas.TextExtent(aLocality);
            if (Rect.Left + size.cx) > Rect.Right then
            begin
              Rect.Left := AViewInfo.BoundsRect.Left;
              Inc(Rect.Top, size.cy);
            end;

            { draw the text item }
            DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, pchar(aLocality), Length(aLocality), Rect, DT_LEFT or DT_NOPREFIX);
            Inc(Rect.Left, size.cx);
          end;
        end;

        ADone := true;
      end;
    end;

  finally
    aLocalities.Free;
    aFaultLocalities.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Usually you spin up a thread for a back ground processes that can take a while and can send updates to the UI. Rarely, do you include components or forms in threads. If the grid is loading slow then I would see if there is a way you put up an hourglass cursor and go and look for a property or setting on the grid that can help speed things up..

Comment: Thanks @Irb I add the function in the post, I had try to make the function a little lite but I think it can't be done much more than what it is (without change components) I have the hourglass  cursor displaying but I don't want to freeze the UI (what is happening at the moment)

Comment: Call the Application.ProcessMessages

Comment: From the quick look at your method code it seems this function is used for custom drawing of your grid cells. This means that you won't be able to simply move this method to separate thread as all UI code needs to be processed by the main thread itself. So I'm afraid you will have to go and try refactoring the methods code itself to try to get better performance out of it. Also you might want to check whether this function is executed only for visible cells or also for those that are currently not visible.

Comment: Also you might rather seek help on dedicated devExpress forum instead (https://community.devexpress.com/forums/) as the people there better knows the inner workings of devExpress components and where you can gain most of the performance out.

Comment: Thanks @SilverWarior I will post this code on their and see if they can help me improve the performance on this code, I appreciate.

Comment: Dont forget to include the code for aFault := FtvdFaults.tvdGetFault(AFaultId); Because it might/might not be there the problem is

Comment: Removing StringReplace from the callback function will allways help.

Comment: You could use aLocalities.Text := AText. aLocalities.CommaText and  aFaultLocalities.Text := aFault.tvdLocalities.CommaText. It would be better to have you object generating this text because then it's only done once.

Comment: Don't use FtvdTree.GetColumnByFieldName ... Use the Column it self ex FaultIdColumn.ItemIndex

Comment: Make sure aFaultLocalities is sorted.

Comment: It's a complex function that does a lot. You have to work out where the bottlenecks are. I don't think we can do that since we don't have the full picture.

Comment: If you want a library to send a block for background processing then take a look at OmniThreadLibrary.

Comment: thanks guys I will be testing all the suggestions and give you guys feedback over the next few days

Answer (score 2):

If you sum up my comments then it should be more or less this.

Try that at let us know how it worked out for you. Since I don't have a working example it might not be 100% correct.

```
procedure TtvdAvaOutageManagementForm.CallbackCustomDrawPreviewCell(Sender: TcxCustomTreeList; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxTreeListEditCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
const
  AlignFlag = DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_END_ELLIPSIS;
  cnFontColor = clBlue;
var
  AFaultId: variant;
  aFault: TtvdFault;
  aLocalities, aFaultLocalities: TStringList;
  i: integer;
  aLocality: string;
  Rect: TRect;
  size: TSize;
  AText: string;
begin
  { colour the preview text blue }
  ACanvas.Font.Color := cnFontColor;
  AText := AViewInfo.DisplayValue;
  aLocalities := TStringList.Create;
  aFaultLocalities := TStringList.Create;
  try
    AFaultId := AViewInfo.Node.Values[FaultIdColumn.ItemIndex];
    if not VarIsNull(AFaultId) then
    begin
      ACanvas.Brush.Color := COLOR_FAULT;    
      aFault := FtvdFaults.tvdGetFault(AFaultId);

      if Assigned(aFault) then
      begin
        ACanvas.Brush.Color := aFault.tvdFaultColor;

        ACanvas.Brush.Color := aFault.tvdFaultColor;
        ACanvas.FillRect(AViewInfo.BoundsRect);
        CopyRect(Rect, AViewInfo.BoundsRect);
        InflateRect(Rect, -1, -1);
        Inc(Rect.Left, FtvdTree.OptionsView.IndicatorWidth);
        ACanvas.Font.Color := cnFontColor;

        { if all the localities are in the fault then bold the preview text,
          else need to do it manually (i.e. only bold the localities that are
          in the fault }

        if aFault.tvdAllLocalities then
        begin
          ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
          ACanvas.DrawTexT(AText, AViewInfo.BoundsRect, AlignFlag);
        end
        else
        begin
          CopyRect(Rect, AViewInfo.BoundsRect);

          aLocalities.CommaText:= AText;

          aFaultLocalities.CommaText := aFault.tvdLocalities;
          aFaultLocalities.Sorted := True;

          for i := 0 to aLocalities.Count - 1 do
          begin
            ACanvas.Font.Style := [];
            { draw a comma if this is not the first locality }
            if i > 0 then
            begin
              size := ACanvas.TextExtent(',');
              DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, ', ', 1, Rect, DT_LEFT or DT_NOPREFIX);
              Inc(Rect.Left, size.cx);
            end;

            aLocality := aLocalities[i];
            if aFaultLocalities.IndexOf(aLocality) >= 0 then
            begin
              ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
            end;

            size := ACanvas.TextExtent(aLocality);
            if (Rect.Left + size.cx) > Rect.Right then
            begin
              Rect.Left := AViewInfo.BoundsRect.Left;
              Inc(Rect.Top, size.cy);
            end;

            { draw the text item }
            DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, pchar(aLocality), Length(aLocality), Rect, DT_LEFT or DT_NOPREFIX);
            Inc(Rect.Left, size.cx);
          end;
        end;

        ADone := true;
      end;
    end;

  finally
    aLocalities.Free;
    aFaultLocalities.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks, thats is pretty handy and helpful I will be testing it, I give you a positive for the effort of summer up everything, I didn't test it yet but I am doing it soon. I will let you now!

Comment: It is better to include and merge mentioned comments into the answer